# How to print a html code using onclick() method via PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this button:  `<input type="submit" name="submit5" class="btn" value="Tarih ekle"  onclick="tarih_alani_yap()" />`

When i click it i want to add this code which is between  tags. It doesnt matter how many click , if user wants to add 5 times it must be okay.

```
<? function tarih_alani_yap() {?>
    <tr>
      <td class="left" valign="top">
          <label>2.Talep Edilen Tarih Aralığı:  <span class="required">*</span></label>
      </td>
      <td class="right">
          <? if ($akis_kademe == "ekle") { ?>
          <input class="text" type="text" size="11" name="rezerv_bas_tarih2" id="rbt" 
                 onclick='scwNextAction=tarih_degisti.runsAfterSCW(this); scwShow(this,event);'
                 value="<?= (!empty($rez_bilgi['rezerv_bas_zaman'])) ? strftime("%d %b %Y", tarih_yap($rez_bilgi['rezerv_bas_zaman'])) : '' ?>" />

          <label>-</label>
          <input class="text" type="text" size="11" name="rezerv_bit_tarih2" id="rbt2" 
                 onclick='scwNextAction=tarih_kontrol.runsAfterSCW(this); scwShow(this,event);'
                 value="<?= (!empty($rez_bilgi['rezerv_bit_zaman'])) ? strftime("%d %b %Y", tarih_yap($rez_bilgi['rezerv_bit_zaman'])) : '' ?>" />

          <? } else echo strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M", tarih_yap($rez_bilgi['rezerv_bas_zaman'], true)) . ' - ' . strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M", tarih_yap($rez_bilgi['rezerv_bit_zaman'], true)) ?>
      </td>
  </tr> 


<? 
}?>
```

Comment: You can't directly call PHP code from JS. You'd need to use AJAX.

Comment: I dont have to use JS actually. All i wanna know how to add one time per one click? @JonStirling

Comment: u have to use js, for php only work before content gets to browser, clear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following jQuery function:

```
$("#buttonID").click(function(){
        $("div#divID").append("<div style='color:green'>Appended text</div>");
    });
```

Hope it helps. =)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use js as php only work before content gets to browser. If the content you want to add is not added, you can echo them in hidden textarea, and append the code when you click it. If you want the content changes with time or when a file is deleted, ajax is needed for it.

```js
$('.js-append').click(function() {
  $('.js-container').append($('.js-append-content').val());
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="js-append">append</a>
<div class="js-container"></div>
<textarea class="hidden js-append-content">
  <?php echo 'your content ';?> test content<br>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this, but what you can is call ajax, which from the other hand can call php script

```
$("#buttonID").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'your-script.php',
    data: { parameters }
    success: function( data ) {
    //do what you got to do : >
    }
  });      
});
```

so in php script you do your if statement, then success function parameter is what php returns/prints, based on that response you can do your job